# zsh having right prompt on same level as left using prezto

Tags: git, zsh, prezto, zsh-zle

I'm new to `zsh` and also [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto). Now as in my bash shell I want to have the current path on the left and my current branch at the right as you can see in the picture so far so good.....

[image: Prompt]

... Now the problem is the right part of the prompt is in the second line and not in the one the path is in!

```
# Define prompts.
PROMPT="
[ ${_prompt_steeef_colors[3]}%n%f@${_prompt_steeef_colors[2]}%m%f ] ${_prompt_steeef_colors[5]}%~%f 
"'$python_info[virtualenv]'"$ "
RPROMPT='${vcs_info_msg_0_}'
```

(Complete source code: [here](https://github.com/lony/dotFiles/blob/master/.zprezto/modules/prompt/functions/prompt_lony_setup))

> How can I achieve both path and branch at the same line in my custom
>   prezto prompt?

Comment: I would suggest extending `PROMPT` to print the information at the right place and drop the use of `RPROMPT`. [This answer on U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250457/52652) should help you with that. Also, I found that using literal newlines in `PROMPT` can lead to some issues: For me it sometimes led to the last line of the previous output overwritten by the prompt when a line in the prompt was exactly as long as the terminal wide (which may happen longer paths; and it was very irritating that `ls` seemed to show an empty directory, where I was expecting to see a single file).

Comment: To complex for me :( I tried.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about rendering artifacts when resizing windows, you can use control characters to hack this functionality in:

```
local _lineup=$'\e[1A'
local _linedown=$'\e[1B'
RPROMPT=%{${_lineup}%}"some stuff"%{${_linedown}%}
```

I found this here: https://superuser.com/questions/357107/zsh-right-justify-in-ps1/737454#737454